# How do I make Object.entries available in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, polyfills

In my angular-cli-built app (which is currently using TypeScript 2.0.3) I want to be able to use this decomposition-based iterator:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {

}
```

What do I have to do in order to have it recognized:

- upgrade TypeScript?
- use a polyfill?

  - if so: how do I import it - in individual .ts files or in a config file to make it globally available?
- use a third-party library?

Comment: Shame the question was marked as duplicate, because none of the answers in the dupes actually provided a working solution for me. Would be happy to answer my own question.

Comment: add "es2019" to ur tsconfig lib array

Answer (score 15):

You need to add

```
"lib": [ "es2017.object" ]
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8482#issuecomment-262847071

Comment: I assume you meant the `tsconfig.file` - where I had already had `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]`. Adding `"es2017.object"` to it didn't change anything for me, so I followed your answer and found a suggestion to import `import "core-js/library";` which didn't change anything either. The entries are still not found on the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, don't know then.

Comment: You used `core-js` together with `es2017.object`? Seems to be required.

Comment: Yes, exactly so - `"es2017.object"` combined with `import "core-js/library"`. tsconfig excerpt: `"lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017.object"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",`

Comment: "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es2017.object"
    ]
worked for me.