# Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, google-apis-explorer

I have this project I am working on.
the idea is to retrieve books from google book API, using angular 4

I am struggling to understand how to read the JSON response, I am still learning Angular.
I was searching the internet and found this source code on GitHub
[google bookstore](https://github.com/abhishekramkrishna002/Google-books)

I am getting the following error

```
Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

for this line

```
  let bookResponse = JSON.parse(body);
```

I am not sure if I am doing it the correct way.
appreciate your help

below is my method for send HTTP request.

```
  getBooks(searchparam: any){
let par = new HttpParams();
par.set('q', searchparam);

return this.httpClient.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', {
  params : new HttpParams().set('q',searchparam)
}).map(
  (response: Response) => {
    let data = response;

    return data;
  }
);
```

}

below is the method to get data from HTTP request and read JSON response

```
  getBook() {

const dataArrya = this.searchForm.get('param').value;

console.log(dataArrya);
this.requestService.getBooks(dataArrya)
  .subscribe(
    response  => {
      this.printData(response)
    //  console.log(this.bookData);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error)
  );
```

}

```
 private printData(res: Response) {

let body = res;
let books: Array<Book> = new Array<Book>();
let bookResponse = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(bookResponse);
console.dir(bookResponse);
for (let book of bookResponse.items) {
  books.push({
    title:book.volumeInfo.title,
    subTitle: book.volumeInfo.subTitle,
    categories: book.volumeInfo.categories,
    authors: book.volumeInfo.authors,
    rating: book.volumeInfo.rating,
    pageCount: book.volumeInfo.pageCount,
    image: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks === undefined ? '' : book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    description: book.volumeInfo.description,
    isbn: book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers,
    previewLink: book.volumeInfo.previewLink
  });
}

}
```

Comment: By the way, there's an error in the code above. HttpParams instances are immutable, and `.set` should be chained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210406/angular-4-3-httpclient-set-params . This `par.set('q', searchparam)` won't work.

Comment: Thanks Estus, it worked for me because i have only one parameter, but if i have more, then it is a problem.

Comment: It works because you have correct code in another place, `params : new HttpParams().set('q',searchparam)`

Answer (score 11):

`JSON.parse` takes a string, but you're passing it an Angular `Response`, which is an object (not a string). In order to convert an Angular `Response` to a string, you can call `toString` on it, like this:

```
let bookResponse = JSON.parse(body.toString());
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

As [the reference](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) states,

> The responseType value determines how a successful response body will be parsed. If responseType is the default json, a type interface for the resulting object may be passed as a type parameter to request().

`HttpClient` `get` already parses the response with `JSON.parse` by default and there is no need to call it twice.

The result is plain object, not `Response` (it belongs to [`Http` API](https://angular.io/api/http/Response) and can be confused with [`Response` global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) when not being imported).

The mentioned [repository](https://github.com/abhishekramkrishna002/Google-books) uses Angular 2 and `Http`, and the code from there isn't suitable here. `HttpClient` is newer API that was introduced in Angular 4. The main practical difference between `Http` and `HttpClient` is that the latter doesn't require to add `.map(response: Response => response.json())` to the request.

Comment: Please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214946/argument-of-type-object-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-httpresponsea