# Retrieve a value from JSON response from Web API

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry if this is obvious but I just cant seem to get my head around it and I cannot think of the right way to phrase my google query (even though I have been trying).

I have the following `JSON` which is returned from a web API.

```
{"firstName":"Joe","surname":"bloggs","email":"joe.bloggs@gmail.com"}
```

I want to access the email from the `JSON` in my angular app and I getting the data with the followig:

```js
this.auth.getUserDetails(username, password).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
 })
```

`data.email` doesnt work,
`data[2].value` doesnt work

How do I specifically reference the `email` from the `data` object?

## Update

I have just checked the network response to the Web API call and it returns this:

```
"{\"firstName\":\"Joe\",\"surname\":\"bloggs\",\"email\":\"joe.bloggs@gmail.com\"}"
```

but just to confirm if I print data to the console I get the first line above.

## Update2

Code from getUserDetails:

```js
getUserDetails(username, password){
    let params = new HttpParams({ fromString: 'username=' + username + '&password=' + [password]  });
    return this.httpclient.get(this.myUrl, { params });
  }
```

Comment: What does console.log(data) prints?

Comment: Can you please post the code for `getUserDetails()`? Also, what version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @ukn the console prints the first line shown in the question above

Comment: Where is data.email not working?

Comment: in the console.log

Comment: If the json you showed us is what is printed by console.log(data), console.log(data.email) is surely working

Comment: I thought it should as well but it doesnt.  it states 'undefined'

Comment: @ukn I have updated the question with some more info

Comment: Try const obj = JSON.parse(data) then obj.email

Comment: Hi I tried that earlier and got 'Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.'

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer here - [Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997326/argument-of-type-response-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string) and @ukn's comment I was able to do the following:

```js
let userDetails = JSON.parse(data.toString());
console.log(userDetails.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you created an interface for your user and it would simplify this problem and other problems you would have in future.

```js
export interface user {
firstname: string,
surname: string,
email: string
}
```

Then using it to get the data like:

```js
return this.httpclient.get<user>(this.myUrl, { params });
```

Then you can use the data like you want after the response.

```js
this.auth.getUserDetails(username, password).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.email)
 })
```