# Angular HttpClient params with method GET do not work

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular-http

I wanna ask you about params with get method.
I have something like this:

```
    path = 'https://example.com/api';
    const params = new HttpParams();
    params.append('http', 'angular');
    return this.http.get(path, {params: params});
```

I thought I would have url like:

> www.example.com/api?http=angular

but actually when I check that in network tab in chrome, request url is

> www.example.com/api

What should I do when I want to have path: www.example.com/api?http=angular
And is it possible to check request url of used method without chrome? I mean in service where I use that method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4.3 - HttpClient set params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210406/angular-4-3-httpclient-set-params)

Answer (score 9):

You need to reassign after the `append` function call. It returns a new [**HttpParams**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) object.

```
const params = new HttpParams().append('http', 'angular');
```

This is [**the documentation of append**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#append). You can see that it returns *HttpParams* instance

```
append(param: string, value: string): HttpParams

Construct a new body with an appended value for the given parameter name.
```

> And is it possible to check request url of used method without chrome ?

You can create an [**HttpInterceptor**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and see the whole url which will be used in the `intercept` function implementation.