# Angular's httpclient get with params to ASP.Net Core controller

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm working on a simple get with search parameters, trying to use Angular's httpclient with HttpParams

```
  getOptions(id1: string, id2: string): Promise<string[]> {
return new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
  var params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
  params.set('id1', id1;
  params.set('id2', id2);
  this.httpClient.get<string[]>(`${this.appConfig.apiUrl}/api/task/getoptions`, {params: params}).subscribe(resp => {
    resolve(resp);
  }, error => {
    reject(error);
  })
});
}
```

My endpoint looks like that:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<List<string>> GetOptions([FromQuery] string id1, [FromHeader] string id2)
    {
        //...do something
    }
```

I tried all attributes like [FromQuery], [FromForm], [FromHeader],... but the data I send never arrives to the controller, although method/endpoint is being called. The values are just null.

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

and finally I found that the solution is on stackoverflow already...

[Angular HttpClient params with method GET do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219882/angular-httpclient-params-with-method-get-do-not-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)