# Spring boot http POST @RequestParam multiple parameters

Tags: angular, http, typescript, spring-boot, httpclient

I have a spring boot `admin server` and a `angular-client` front part. I'm trying to send some data from my front to my server using HTTPClient but somehow I'm getting the following error during my request, but first here is my code :

POST request in `angular-client` :

```
  runBatch(id: number, stateUpd: string): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/update_state', {id, stateUpd}, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Controller in `angular-client` :

```
changeBatchState(state: string): void {
        if(this.selection.selected.length >= 1){
            this.selection.selected.forEach(batchInstance =>{
                if(batchInstance.batchState == 'CRASHED' || 'KILLED' || 'SUBMITTED'){
                    console.log(batchInstance.id + " setting to RUNNABLE...");
                    this.dataTableService.runBatch(batchInstance.id, state).subscribe(event => {
                        if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                         console.log('POST /update_state sending...');   
                        }
                        else if(event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                         console.log('Request completed !');   
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log(batchInstance.id + ' can not set to RUNNABLE');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Controller in `admin server` :

```
    @PostMapping("/update_state")
    public ResponseEntity<String> batchChangeState(@RequestParam("id") int id, @RequestParam("stateUpd") String stateUpd) {
        try {
            log.i("INSIDE CONTROLLER");
            log.i("BATCH INSTANCE ID : " + id);
            log.i("UPDATE REQUESTED : " + stateUpd);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Batch instance: " + id + " updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body("Fail to update batch instance " + id);
        }
    }
```

and here the error I get during the request :

```
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8870/update_state", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8870/update_state: 400 OK", error: "{\"timestamp\":1517473012190,\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"exception\":\"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException\",\"message\":\"Required int parameter 'id' is not present\",\"path\":\"/update_state\"}" }
```

I don't understand where it comes from since I'm sending the id correctly in my POST request, any ideas ?

Comment: Can you check your post request in developer console? You can try to send  parameters like this: new HttpRequest('POST', `\`/update_state?id=${id}&stateUpd=${stateUpd}\``,...

Comment: I'm getting this error trying like that : `Error parsing HTTP request header`
right now debugging to give you the request form..

Comment: it does not remplace ${id} and ${stateUpd} by their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/update_state', {id, stateUpd}, {
```

will create a request where {id, stateUpd} are in the body, not in the queryParams.

You should do

```
// change : Body = null, and data are in options.params    
runBatch(id: number, stateUpd: string): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/update_state', null, {
          reportProgress: true,
          responseType: 'text',
          params: new HttpParams().set('id', id.toString()).set('stateUpd', stateUpd);
        });
        return this.http.request(req);
      }
```

Comment: params is of type HttpParams, I'm getting a type error doing like that.

Comment: what is your angular version ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210406/angular-4-3-httpclient-set-params for the good way of adding HttpParams

Comment: params: {
          id: id.toString(),
          stateUpd: stateUpd
      }

Comment: It should be like that but there is still a type error on id: id.toString() for some unknow reasons..

Comment: Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id: string; stateUpd: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'HttpParams'.
(method) Number.toString(radix?: number): string

Comment: and if I do as you said i got this :

Comment: Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id: number; stateUpd: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'HttpParams'.
(property) id: number

Comment: I'm trying with new HttpParams().set(param1).set(param2)

Comment: this worked : const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('id', id.toString())
    .set('stateUpd', stateUpd);

Comment: could you update your answer so I can validate it :)