# calculating array of array values in index manner

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am receiving an object from server that seems something like

```
    var response = [
         {
          "id":"1",
          "series":{
                    "eoy":[10,20,30,40,50,60],
                    "eom":[20,30,40,50,60],
                    "now":[30,40,50,60,70,80]
                   }
         }
         {
          "id":"2",
          "series":{
                   "eoy":[30,40,20,50,10],
                   "eom":[20,10,50,70,20,50],
                   "now":[30,10,70,20]
                   }
         }
    ]
```

inside series, there are many keys and values. just for problem purpose I wrote 3 pairs. Now I want to add those arrays in such a manner that I will get the result as a object which should be like

```
var result = {
     "eoy":[40,60,50,90,60,60],
     "eom":[40,40,90,120,80,50],
     "now":[60,50,120,80,70,80]
}
```

In this, I'm adding adding all the eoys and making it as one array and doing with every series member. Is there any way to make a single object of all calculated values.

Comment: Let me see your implementing code first @Yash Jain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group the array and objects. Use `Object.entries` to convert the object into array. And use `forEach` to loop thru your arrays.

```js
let arr = [{"id": "1","series": {"eoy": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],"eom": [20, 30, 40, 50, 60],"now": [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]}},{"id": "2","series": {"eoy": [30, 40, 20, 50, 10],"eom": [20, 10, 50, 70, 20, 50],"now": [30, 10, 70, 20]}}];

let result = arr.reduce((c, {series}) => {
  Object.entries(series).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    c[k] = c[k] || [];
    v.forEach((o, i) => {
      c[k][i] = c[k][i] || 0;
      c[k][i] += o;
    });
  })
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

---

You can use `for` `in` to loop thru your object if `Object.entries` is not available.

```js
let arr = [{"id": "1","series": {"eoy": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],"eom": [20, 30, 40, 50, 60],"now": [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]}},{"id": "2","series": {"eoy": [30, 40, 20, 50, 10],"eom": [20, 10, 50, 70, 20, 50],"now": [30, 10, 70, 20]}}];

let result = arr.reduce((c, {series}) => {
  for (var k in series) {
    c[k] = c[k] || [];
    series[k].forEach((o, i) => {
      c[k][i] = c[k][i] || 0;
      c[k][i] += o;
    });
  }
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same without using Object.entries()

Comment: Yes there is, is this fore `node.js`? @YashJain

Comment: I am making app in angular5 and when I tried Object.entries(). It says, "property 'entries()' doesn't exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' "

Comment: You can check to add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410029/how-do-i-make-object-entries-available-in-typescript

Comment: I added another sample code block without `Object.entries()` please check

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`, like this:

```js
const input=[{"id":"1","series":{"eoy":[10,20,30,40,50,60],"eom":[20,30,40,50,60],"now":[30,40,50,60,70,80]}},{"id":"2","series":{"eoy":[30,40,20,50,10],"eom":[20,10,50,70,20,50],"now":[30,10,70,20]}}];
const output = input.reduce((a, { series }) => {
  Object.entries(series).forEach(([key, arr]) => {
    if (!a[key]) a[key] = [];
    const sumArr = a[key];
    arr.forEach((num, i) => sumArr[i] = (sumArr[i] || 0) + num);
  });
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

```css
{
 "eoy":[40,60,50,90,60,60],
 "eom":[40,40,90,120,80,50],
 "now":[60,50,120,80,70,80]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","series":{"eoy":[10,20,30,40,50,60],"eom":[20,30,40,50,60],"now":[30,40,50,60,70,80]}},{"id":"2","series":{"eoy":[30,40,20,50,10],"eom":[20,10,50,70,20,50],"now":[30,10,70,20]}}];

let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  /* For each item in the array, iterate over each entry
   ** in series and sum it in the accumulator object. */
  Object.entries(c.series).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    a[k] = a[k] || []; 
    v.forEach((n, i) => a[k][i] = a[k][i] ? a[k][i] + n : n);
  });
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Without Object.entries

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","series":{"eoy":[10,20,30,40,50,60],"eom":[20,30,40,50,60],"now":[30,40,50,60,70,80]}},{"id":"2","series":{"eoy":[30,40,20,50,10],"eom":[20,10,50,70,20,50],"now":[30,10,70,20]}}];

let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  /* For each item in the array, iterate over each entry
   ** in series and sum it in the accumulator object. */
  Object.keys(c.series).forEach((k) => {
    let v = c.series[k];
    a[k] = a[k] || []; 
    v.forEach((n, i) => a[k][i] = a[k][i] ? a[k][i] + n : n);
  });
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can we do the same without using Object.entries() coz when I tried to do the same in my angular5 app. It says " property 'entries()' doesn't exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' "

Comment: @YashJain - Updated.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.... just want to know. Is there any performance difference between Object.entries() or what you used instead of Object.entries(). Asking this because I received answers using Object.entries()

Comment: @YashJain - I doubt there will be any performance issue. Object.entries is used because you can get both the key and value together otherwise with other methods like Object.keys, you will only get the keys and then to get the value you have to access the object again.

Comment: Thanks for info :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var arr = [
 {
  "id":"1",
  "series": {
            "eoy":[10,20,30,40,50,60],
            "eom":[20,30,40,50,60],
            "now":[30,40,50,60,70,80]
           }
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "series":{
           "eoy":[30,40,20,50,10],
           "eom":[20,10,50,70,20,50],
           "now":[30,10,70,20]
           }
 }
];

console.log(arr.map(x=> x.series));
```